# how to get Processor ID using Kernel32.dll

Tags: dll, kernel32

I want to know if there is an Entry point for kernel32.dll , that is related to any processor data (ID , Serial , etc ... )
and I tried to Google it but I didn't find good results .

Note: I already know WMI , but I need something related to Kernel !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it is the best one
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724381(VS.85).aspx

Comment: this is very near , but SYSTEM_INFO Structure contain only ProcessorType and Revision , and no data like Serial number or ID :(